# String is not separating by comma after taking values from data grid view

Tags: vb.net, string, winforms, split

I am working on a winform application. I have a grid view. I am taking data grid view first column value to my string variable...so my code is like this

```
 Dim cnt As Integer = DGVall.RowCount
        Dim tbarcode As String
        Dim tbarcodepass As String
        For i = 0 To cnt - 2
            If Not IsDBNull(DGVall.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) Then
                tbarcode = DGVall.Item(0, 1).Value
                tbarcodepass += tbarcode.Split(New Char() {","c})(0)
            End If

        Next
```

but getting result is not proper

the string is not separating by comma.

Comment: `Split` returns an array of strings. What do you want to do with that comma-separated list? For example for adding the first string in the array do `tbarcode.Split(New Char() {","c})[0]`

Comment: split will return array, so whatever item your have to do += you have to give like tbarcode.Split(New Char() {","c})[0]

Comment: i want to get all values of tbarcode to tbarcodepass variable by seprated by comma,,if example 12,23,45,56 like thise

Comment: anyone, why do I see this question in `C#` tag list?

Comment: sir i changed code like this:tbarcodepass += tbarcode.Split(New Char() {","c})(0) but sting not seprating by comma..

Comment: `New Char() {","c}` in vb.net write simpler just `{","c}`

Comment: i am working on vb.net apllication only

Comment: String.Split is to split strings, i.e. make them into smaller pieces. String.Join is to join several strings from a collection (e.g. an array) into one string, with a separator. I don't think you want either of those. It *looks* like you want `tbarcodepass &= tbarcode & ","`, then remove the last `,` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get data and formatted as array? or just string like a,b,c,d?

You can use List(Of T) Method to Store the value as array format, then joining them and add delimiter (,)

Sample:

```
Dim tbarcodepass As List(Of String)= New List(Of String)()
Dim cnt As Integer = DGVall.RowCount
    Dim tbarcode As String
    For i = 0 To cnt - 2
        If Not IsDBNull(DGVall.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) Then
            tbarcode = DGVall.Item(0, 1).Value
            tbarcodepass.Add(tbarcode) 'Add each value from cell to the list
        End If
    Next

Dim tbarcodepass_comma as String = String.Join(",", tbarcodepass)

MsgBox(tbarcodepass_comma)
```